# MailGun returning error 421 on Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, mailgun

I have a free tier account on MailGun and I'm trying to configure the application to send the user a token to reset his password but I keep getting the following error in my browser console.
`"Expected response code "220" but got code "421", with message "421 Server busy, too many connections".`

This is how my  `.env` file is configured

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Presumably the server is busy and has too many connections. What kind of a solution are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `smtp` config? Laravel comes with a Mailgun driver built in. You should be setting your `MAILER` to `mailgun` and then configuring your mailgun domain, key, and email address.

See here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#mailgun-driver